# capitalizedString doesn't capitalize correctly words starting with numbers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using the NSString method [myString capitalizedString], to capitalize all words of my string.

However capitalization doesn't work very well for words starting with numbers.

```
i.e. 2nd chance
```

becomes

```
2Nd Chance
```

Even if n is not the first letter of the word.

thanks

Comment: This might help: http://www.pittle.org/weblog/how-to-capitalize-a-nsstring-instance-while-keeping-roman-numerals-all-capitalized_536.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to roll your own solution to this problem. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString) state that you may not get the specified behavior using that function for multi-word strings and for strings with special characters. Here's a pretty crude solution

```
NSString *text = @"2nd place is nothing";

// break the string into words by separating on spaces.
NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

// create a new array to hold the capitalized versions.
NSMutableArray *newWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// we want to ignore words starting with numbers.
// This class helps us to determine if a string is a number.
NSNumberFormatter *num = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];

for (NSString *item in words) {
    NSString *word = item; 
    // if the first letter of the word is not a number (numberFromString returns nil)
    if ([num numberFromString:[item substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]] == nil) {
        word = [item capitalizedString]; // capitalize that word.
    } 
    // if it is a number, don't change the word (this is implied).
    [newWords addObject:word]; // add the word to the new list.
}

NSLog(@"%@", [newWords description]);
```

Comment: Nice solution. I switched `[newWords description];` for `[[newWords valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];` however, as the former will return a string that contains parentheses and newline characters.

Comment: Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this seems to be the general behaviour of capitalizedString.

Perhaps a not so nice workaround / hack would be to replace each number with a string before the transformation, and then change it back afterwards.

So, "2nd chance" -> "xyznd chance" -> "Xyznd Chance" -> "2nd Chance"

Comment: Indeed it is not so nice hack, is there any other solution ?